# Why does this query on a local sqlite DB take 4 minutes to execute?

Tags: sql, performance, sqlite, database-performance

I'm executing the query from [SQLite Expert Personal](http://www.sqliteexpert.com/) on a local DB that is about 6mb in size. My machine is running Windows 7 with 4GB ram on an Intel i5 CPU (3.1GHz). I would expect this to complete within seconds because everything is local, but for some reason it executes in 277667 ms (around 4.5 minutes). Any ideas on why this takes so long for a relatively small data set? Let me know if you need any more information

```
TABLE "userlist" contains about 7k records and 4 columns
TABLE "employeeinfo" contains about 30k records and 8 columns
```

Query:

```
CREATE TABLE join1 AS
SELECT a.appname AS APPNAME, a.appid AS APPID,  a.perm AS PERMS, a.holdflag AS HOLDFLAG, b.FirstName AS USERFIRST, b.LastName AS USERLAST, b.DeptName AS USERDEPT,
b.TermDate AS USERTERMDATE, b.logonid AS USERHRLOGON, b.empnum AS USEREMPNUM, b.persontype AS USERPERSONTYPE, b.mgrlogonid AS MGRHRLOGON
FROM userlist AS a
LEFT JOIN
employeeinfo AS b
ON a.appid LIKE b.logonid;
```

**UPDATE:**
My execution time went from 4.5 minutes down to 110 milliseconds after doing the following:

1. Imported my data again, with the join columns(a.appid, b.logonid) both being all lowercase, so I could use '=' instead of LIKE
2. Created an index on a.appid and b.logonid
3. Increased the PRAGMA cache_size from 2000 (default) to 100000. I just read this only lasts for the current session. When I closed and reopened my DB, the cache_size was indeed back to 2000
4. Increased the PRAGMA page_size from 1024 to 4096 (apparently this only makes a difference if you declare before creating your first table, can someone confirm?)
5. Changed PRAGMA journal_mode from 'delete' to 'wal'. I then had to change this to 'memory' because the 'wal' type is not compatible with the version of Python I'm using (2.7.5)
   6.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The expression `a.appid LIKE b.logonid` cannot be optimized, not even with a case-insensitive index on `appid`.
Therefore, the database has to check every record in `userlist` against every record in `employeeinfo`, so there are 7K × 30K = 210M comparisons.

You should ensure that the strings in these table have a canonical capitalization so that you can use a plain `=` comparison.
Alternatively, create an additional column where you store a lower-case version of the string.

Answer (score 4):

You're not specifying wildcards so don't use `LIKE` in your `ON` condition - change it to `=`, and make sure that `employeeinfo.logonid` is indexed.

Comment: While it would be odd, there is nothing preventing the `b.logonid` column to contain those wildcards.

Comment: If I use = will 'MikE' join with 'mike'? Or does it depend on how the text is encoded? I'm using LIKE currently to account for identical strings with different capitalizations.

Comment: @JamesNicholson If this was MySQL I'd say yes. For SQLite I don't know, but if you're using vague data like that then queries are likely to be protracted. Some normalisation and indexing of data will probably be appropriate. As is so often the case in software: try it and see.